# How to transmit voice signal and receive on radio?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency

I want to transmit data like radio stations do.

Like radio stations broadcast music and etc. using frequency, so I am also curious to know about it that actually how it works.

I also want to make such a device that will broadcast my data or voice in my apartment and if anybody will on that frequency they should hear my broadcast data.

Is it possible or not ?
If yes then anyone please guide me.
And what happen if i ll broadcast on same frequency on which already data is broadcasting ?

I want to know about radio signals, so any guidance on it.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you have to know is that transmitting on the FM band is something heavily regulated. Your emitter must not exceed a specific power or range. Check the legislation of the country in which the device operates.

For this you will need an FM transmitter. You can buy them [pre-made](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F8Z439/), or build them with [very few parts](http://www.electroschematics.com/83/mini-fm-transmitter-max2606/). It might even be possible to get it to work without additional hardware and some creative hacking (some smartphones or tablets use the BCM4329 chip for example, which is capable of FM transmission).

> And what happen if i ll broadcast on same frequency on which already data is broadcasting ?

The strongest signal wins.

Comment: Ok, now I got the right one. Thanks for the guidance. Now I am going to make my own FM transmitter to broadcast signals.

Comment: "Strongest signal wins" is a reasonable approximation when one is a lot stronger than the other. If the difference is not so big, the result is unintelligible.